# Проблема с добавлением в БД

Tags: php

В чем у меня ошибка? Не могу понять. Нужно занести данные из 5-ти полей в базу. У меня ничего не происходит.

```
<?php
// Переменные с формы
$name = $_POST['name'];
$surname = $_POST['surname'];
$day = $_POST['day'];
$month = $_POST['month'];
$year = $_POST['year'];

if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['surname']) && isset($_POST['day'])){


    // Параметры для подключения
   require_once 'bd.php'; // подключаем скрипт
    $db_table = "golden"; // Имя Таблицы БД

    // Подключение к базе данных
    $db = mysql_connect($host,$user,$password) OR DIE("Не могу создать соединение ");

    // Выборка базы
    mysql_select_db("goldenfire",$db);

    // Установка кодировки соединения
    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'",$db);

    $result = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO golden (name,surname,day,month,year) VALUES ('$name','$surname','$day','$month','$year')");

   if ($result == 'true') { ?>
вввв
<?php
}else{
        echo "Информация не занесена в базу данных";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Начните с того, что `$result` надо сранивать не со строкой `'true'` а просто с `true`. А еще лучше просто `if($result)`.
А если не происходит вообще ничего, и не показывается ни одно сообщение, то включите отображение ошибок, возможно у вас пхп 7, но при этом вы используете такой архаизм как расширение `mysql_` которого там нет. А если все вроде как работает, но строки в таблицу не добавляются, то проверьте ошибки запроса, в mysql_ есть и функции для возврата собщения об ошибке

Comment: но вообще, используйте PDO/mysqli, подготовленные выражения и биндинг параметров. не надо подставлять переменные прямиком в тело запроса.